# Query to fetch specific part from a filepath

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have filename field in table which contains value as follows,

Its image files preceding with employee code

> H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\e45432_Sign.jpg
>
> H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\e45434_1418_Sign.jpg
> H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\E45434_age_Sign.jpg
> H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\E45538_Rana_Sign.jpg

Now I want to write SQL query in such a way that I will get only employee numbers from the path
i.e. for example output will be in the following format

```
empno
e45432
e45434
E45538
```

I have tried with following query

```
 select SUBSTRING([FileName],55,6) as empno  from #tmp_filepath
```

it has given me the output I wanted but it's like I'm hardcoding the positions

Comment: [i'm not sure about this but you need something of this kind](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c29bc/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(
     RIGHT(Str,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(Str))-1),
     CHARINDEX('_',RIGHT(Str,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(Str))-1))-1
  )
FROM T
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9ab5/10)</kbd>

Comment: declare @str varchar(50)
select @str=right('H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\E35697_Sign.jpg',
CHARINDEX('\',reverse('H:\KYC_PDF_Cloud_N\Employee\PANCard-CroppedSignatures\E35697_Sign.jpg'))-1)
select left(@str,charindex('_',@str)-1)